# How many displays can I plug into MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

In the MacBook [technical specifications documentation](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP754?locale=da_DK&viewlocale=en_US), I read that it supports up to 2 monitors (or 1, it depends on display parameters).

On Apple’s [Thunderbolt 3  page](https://www.apple.com/thunderbolt/), I read the same info but about a single Thunderbolt 3 port (of which I have 2).

What is the number of monitors I can connect to my MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can plug in a maximum of two monitors**

The technical specifications gives you detailed info about what your specific model’s capabilities are.  In this case, your model MacBook - 2017 13 inch MacBook Pro - has enough bandwidth to support two monitors at 4K or less or just one monitor at 5K.

The Thunderbolt information page gives you a generalized perspective of Thunderbolt’s capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [technical specification](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP754?locale=da_DK&viewlocale=en_US) of your model:

> **Video Support**
>
> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display at millions of colors and:
>
> - One display with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
> - Up to two displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at millions of colors
> - Up to two displays with 3840-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
>
> Thunderbolt 3 digital video output
>
> - Native DisplayPort output over USB‑C
> - VGA, HDMI, DVI, and Thunderbolt 2 output supported using adapters (sold separately)

therefore you can have 3 active screens including the screen of your MacBook.

The 2 connected monitor can have a resolution up to 4K.

If you wish to connect a monitor with higher resolution than 4K (e.g. 5K), you will be able to connect only 1 additional monitor (i.e. 2 active screen configuration).

In general, to be able to connect even more monitors you need to have a dedicated GPU. A similar question was addressed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191287/50712).

Answer (score -1):

I have tried plugging in an Apple thunderbolt display using Apple's own USB-C to thunderbolt adapter (purchased from the apple store) - works great. - I can also connect a Dell 1080p, USB-C monitor -- but not both at the same time. - I am considering trying with a diff monitor.